Importing Data Faster in MATLAB
I have this code in MATLAB:
opts = detectImportOptions("Data-2013.txt");
opts = setvartype(opts,{...});
opts = setvartype(opts,{...},'string');

Table_2013 = readtable('Data-2013.txt',opts);
Table_2014 = readtable('Data-2014.txt',opts);
Table_2015 = readtable('Data-2015.txt',opts);
Table_2016 = readtable('Data-2016.txt',opts);
Table_2017 = readtable('Data-2017.txt',opts);
Table_2018 = readtable('Data-2018.txt',opts);
Table_2019 = readtable('Data-2019.txt',opts);
Table_2020 = readtable('Data-2020.txt',opts);
Table_2021 = readtable('Data-2021.txt',opts);
Table_2022 = readtable('Data-2022.txt',opts);

Table_Merged = [Table_2013;Table_2014;Table_2015;Table_2016;Table_2017;Table_2018;Table_2019;Table_2020;Table_2021;Table_2022];

With all the data in these files (there's a LOT), it's taking several minutes just to import everything. I don't want to have to do this every time I open the app, but is there a faster way? I tried doing parfor loops and memmapfile, but they either don't seem to really improve the speed and the bottleneck is my hardware, or I'm not doing it right. Any suggestion on how to improve speed for reading in these files? Or, to only have to do it once even with closing the file and opening it again?
Here is an example of one entry (among thousands):
med_rec_number_deidentified encounter_id_deidentified   SiteCd  ArrivalTS   ArrivalToRoomTS TriageStartTS   TriageEndTS QuickTriageStartTS  QuickTriageEndTS    AssignedAttendingTS FirstSeenTS FirstLabOrdTS   FirstLabOrdUSER FirstLabOrdID   FirstImgOrdTS   FirstImgOrdUSER FirstImgOrdID   FirstMedOrdTS   FirstMedOrdUSER FirstMedOrdID   DischargeDispoTS    PtDischargeTS   FirstEDAttending    EthnicGroup EthnicBackground    GenderIdentity  LegalSex    MaritalStatus   Race    Age BloodPressure   Systolic    Diastolic   Temperature HeartRate   RespRate    Weight  ChiefComplaint  ESI PhysicianAssignedID MidLevelAssignedID  FinalDxI10  FinalDxNm   EDDisposition   EDDispoProvID   FYI_YN  EDIE_YN ALG01   ALG02   ALG03   ALG04   ALG05   ALG06   ALG07   ALG08   ALG09   ALG10   ALG11   ALG12   ALG13   ALG14   ALG15   ALG16   ALG17   ALG18   ALG19   ALG20
12345678    12345678    FO ED   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 2015-01-01 00:05:45.000 2015-01-01 00:10:04.000 2015-01-01 00:13:00.000 2015-01-01 00:09:00.000 2015-01-01 00:10:02.000 2015-01-01 00:02:00.000 NULL    2015-01-01 00:19:00.000 5390    12345678    2015-01-01 00:19:00.000 5390    12345678    2015-01-01 00:19:00.000 5390    12345678    2015-01-01 01:27:09.000 2015-01-01 01:51:00.000 5390    Non Hispanic/Latino Asia - Vietnamese   NULL    Male    Significant Other   South Asian 41  106/65  106 65  98.4    62  16  NULL    BACK PAIN   ESI 4   5390        M54.50  Low back pain   Discharge   5390    N   N   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

The zeros at the end are dummy codes/booleans. Sorry they don't line up too well, but hopefully that gives you a sense of the data.

It would really help to know what your data looks like... Can you [edit] your question to give an example of what's in the txt files?

@Wolfie I just updated it, let me know if that's helpful or if there is more you'd like to see. I just have to be careful because some of the data could be sensitive.

Does the data change from run-to-run or is it static?  If it is static you could just pre-process and save off as a .mat file.

@GrapefruitIsAwesome Oh I wasn't aware of that feature! It is static, so I'll look into that. Thanks!

@GrapefruitIsAwesome actually, it didn't quite work as expected, somehow using a .mat file to load in the table as a variable made the process take MUCH longer
